# Show $\mathscr{F}$ is precompact

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification

> Suppose$\sum^\infty_{n=0}b_nz^n$ has radius of converge of$\geq 1$ and $\mathscr{F}\subset \{f(z): f(z)=\sum^\infty_{n=0}a_nz^n , \text{holomorphic in unit disc, and for all } n, |a_n|\leq |b_n|\}$. Show that $\mathscr{F}$ is precompact.

What I want to do is show that $\mathscr{F}$ compactly bounded on $\mathbb{D}=$ unit disc, then use Montel's Theorem(A family of holomorphic function on a domain $U$ is precompact if and only if it is compactly bounded).

I start with a compact set $K \subset \mathbb{D}$, and fix $z\in K$ then $f(z)=|\sum a_nz^n|\leq \sum|b_nz^n|$, for $f\in \mathscr{F}$, since $z\in \mathbb{D}$ we have $\sum|b_nz^n|$, which converges to some $M \in \mathbb{C}$. And hence $|f(z)|<M$ for all $z\in K$. Since $K$ was an arbitrary compact subset, we can conclude that $f$ is bounded on all compact subset of $\mathbb{D}$. So $f$ is compactly bounded and hence by Montel it.

I am not too familiar with this set up and have no idea if my proof is anywhere close to what the question want me to show. Can someone help me to check this out? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not find an $M$ that is independent of $z \in K$.

There exists $0<r <1$ such that $|z| \leq r$ for all $z \in K$. The series $\sum b_nr^{n}$ is absolutely convergent. These two facts tell you that you can choose $M$ independent of $z \in K$. Rest of the argument in your proof is fine.